# Json.net used in Web API but not when calling Json.Encode in Razor Template

Tags: c#, json, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a MVC 4 application with both traditional and Web API controllers. Since I'm also using EF5 with code-first I have navigation properties that lead to circular references. I am using `JsonIgnore` attributes on these navigation properties to avoid running into circular reference loops when serializing to Json.

This approach works flawlessly for my Web API controllers, however, when using `Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))` in a traditional controller's Razor template, I get an exception due to the circular references:

> A circular reference was detected while serializing an object

This exception occurs in `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal`. Am I interpreting this correctly in that `Json.Encode` seems to use a different Json encoder (not json.net)? How can I use the configured Json.Net formatter used in Web API from inside Razor templates?

I came up with a workaround where I use the following class

```
namespace MyMVCProject.Globals
{
    public class Helper
    {
        public static string ToJson(object obj)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings);
        }
    }
}
```

so I can use it inside the template: `@Html.Raw(MyMVCProject.Globals.Helper.ToJson(Model))`

This still feels awkward for something I'd expect to be default behaviour of `Json.Encode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, when you call `Json.Encode` you're using a method from the class `System.Web.Helpers.Json`.

If you want to use a different Json encoder, just use it. You can do it just like you've done it, with a helper class that wraps the call to `JsonConvert`, and configures it (including the deisred formatter).

You can include the namespace of your wrapper class so that you can avoid writing the namespace. (You can do it in web.config fro the views, it you frequently use it).

What you cannot do is change the behavior of `Json.Encode` because is an static class member, and its namespace is always included in razor views (because you need more things from the same namespace).

You can also implement it as an extension method to the objects you want to serialize. Only the syntax changes.

Remember that you can also customize the serialization with `[DataContract]` attribute, [as you can see in this page](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size.aspx).

You can also customize the way each member is serialized using other Json.Net attributes attached to the properties of interest in the class definition.